# Is there a way to reduce the number of arguments on a Page return?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, pagination

I'm implementing pagination in my application using Spring and the return of endpoits is `Page`. This object returns a lot of arguments. Is there a way to eliminate some of them?

**The repository extends JpaRepository**

**SERVICE**

```
@Autowired
ClientRepositoy clientRepositoy;

public List<Client> findAllList() {
    return clientRepositoy.findAll();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@Autowired
ServiceClient serviceClient;

@GetMapping("/clients")
public Page<Client> getClients() {
    List<Client> clients = serviceClient.findAllList();
    return new PageImpl<>(convertToDto(clients), PageRequest.of(0, 10), clients.size());
}
```

**JSON RETURN**

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TEST"
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 7,
    "last": true,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 7,
    "empty": false
}
```

I'd like to remove the whole Pageable object, for example:

```
"pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

so we use a class in our response which we cannot modify

we could use a mixin.

if you created your ObjectMapper bean, you could specify your mixin, which will be used during serialization.

it would look like kind of the following code.

the mixin to set the visibility of getter. it will be used during serialization:

```
public interface PageImplMixin {
    @JsonIgnore
    Pageable getPageable();
}
```

own object mapper bean which is configured to use our mixin when the pageimpl class will be serialized:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper().setMixIns(Map.of(PageImpl.class, PageImplMixin.class));
  }
}
```

some link to understand the concept:

[JacksonMixInAnnotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations#mix-ins-to-the-rescue)
[Mix-In Annotations to reuse, decouple](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html)